# Joomla 4 beta - Internal Service Error but no logged error

Tags: custom-component, installation, logs, joomla-4.x

I've installed Joomla 4 beta 7 for development upgrading a Joomla 3 component. I have my logs (apparently) working correctly and I have test error log messages printing to the PHP error log as expected.

I have Joomla error reporting set to `Maximum`.

But when I try installing my component, it gives a pop up saying "Internal Server Error" and then there's nothing in the logs.

Can anyone suggest why there'd be no error messages printing to screen or to the error logs?

My `php-fpm.d/www.conf` shows

```
php_flag[display_errors] = on
php_admin_value[error_log] = /Users/myuser/php_error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 32M
```

and those are reflected in the Joomla phpinfo tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 error was happening in the component installer file-- I still can't say why the error, which was caused by an invalid classname (due to changed Joomla class names in Joomla 4) was not being logged or otherwise printed, since other errors were being logged as expected.

Once the issue was fixed (the classname was updated) the problem was resolved and logging worked as expected.